# Text leaves input box when in columns

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am having a problem where when I fill a html input box like:
[image]

If I add one character more it will fall out like:

[image]

This is the css:

```
form {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edswoosb/)

I have tested this with chrome only.

---

## Update

This **does not** happen in safari

---

## Update 2

This **does not** happen in firefox

---

## [Here is the bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=501141&q=input%20columns&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Comment: its not overflowing for me...

Comment: On chrome?! I wish it was working for me! Haha

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @MattFryer I am on Mac

Comment: on it! Just to confirm you are using chrome?

Comment: Happening for me on Chrome 43.0.2357.124 m, Windows. Seems like time to report a Chrome bug.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't happen for me on Chrome 43.0.2357.124 (64-bit) on OSX Yosemite 10.10.3

Comment: @MattFryer restarted and still happening... Gutted!

Comment: I have Version 43.0.2357.124 (64-bit) on OSX Yosemite 10.10.3 as well!

Comment: I really can't be bothered! Quite a serious issue though!

Comment: umm did you recently drop your computer?.... :)

Comment: No but some bastard split mountain dew on it! Ha!

Comment: It works for me. The only thing I can suggest is to play around with the overflow ie `input{ overflow:hidden;}` or `input{ overflow:auto;}`

Comment: neither work for me :(